# deserialization with the JavaScriptSerializer is missing fields

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

The fields are getting ignored.  I'm successfully getting back a list of 2 objects, but none of the fields are populated.  What am I doing wrong? (Unfortunately I don't have control over the json format.  It arrives in exactly this structure.

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

public void myMethod {
  string myContent = @"
  [
    {
        "my_object": {
            "city": "city 1", 
            "myAge": 15
        }
    },
    {
        "my_object": {
            "city": "city 2", 
            "myAge": 18
        }
    }
  ]";

  JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  List<my_object> list = serializer.Deserialize<List<my_object>>(myContent);

}

public class json_content {
  public string city { get; set; }
  public int myAge { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code solves your problem:

```
public void myMethod()
{
    string myContent = @"
        [
            {
                ""json_content"": {
                    ""city"": ""city 1"", 
                    ""myAge"": 15
                }
            },
            {
                ""json_content"": {
                    ""city"": ""city 2"", 
                    ""myAge"": 18
                }
            }
        ]";

    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    List<wrapper> list = serializer.Deserialize<List<wrapper>>(myContent);
}

public class wrapper
{
    public json_content json_content { get; set; }
}

public class json_content
{
    public string city { get; set; }
    public int myAge { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Same problem as the below answer.  I don't have control over the JSON format unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

You have list of objects with one property `json_content` in your JSON, but expect list directly containing `json_content` objects.

Most likely fix is to remove intermediate object from JSON (if you control it):

```
[
  {
     "city": "city 1", 
     "myAge": 15
  },...
];
```

If you don't control JSON add outer class:

```
class JsonOuterContent
{ 
   public JsonContent json_content;
}

List<JsonOuterContent> list = serializer
      .Deserialize<List<JsonOuterContent>>(myContent);
```

Comment: I don't control the format of the JSON.  It's coming back from an outside API unfortunately.

Comment: Agreed. If the OP is in any doubt as to what format JavascriptSerializer is to expect why dont they Serialize a List<json_content> and examin the string.

Comment: I changed the initial JSON field names to be less misleading.

Comment: @AdamLevitt I added approximate code to read your JSON. But take note of  Paul Sullivan comment - call serialize on your object to see what is shape of JSON and if it matches expected one.